# C++ equivalent for fscanf

Tags: c++

i would like to translate those code from c to c++

```
 fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &v.x, &v.y, &v.z );
```

and

```
int matches = fscanf(file, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &vIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &nIndex[0], &vIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &nIndex[1], &vIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &nIndex[2] );
```

i couldn't find any document about that on the internet. i suppose to use ifstream and stringstream but everything i read online is quite confusing.

To make it worst, my ISP is having trouble which they blocked some site by accident (cplusplus.com ....) ==!! so i cannot really find anything useful currenly

Can anyone help me con those code. Thank you guy a lot for this

example of file

> v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000  5 v 1.000000
>   -1.000000 1.000000  6 v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000  7 v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000  8 v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000  9 v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001 10 v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 11 v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000 12 vt 0.748573 0.750412 13 vt 0.749279 0.501284 14 vt 0.999110 0.501077 15 vt 0.999455 0.750380 16 vt 0.250471 0.500702
>   17 vt 0.249682 0.749677 18 vt 0.001085 0.750380 19 vt 0.001517
>   0.499994 20 vt 0.499422 0.500239 21 vt 0.500149 0.750166 22 vt 0.748355 0.998230 23 vt 0.500193 0.998728 24 vt 0.498993 0.250415 25 vt 0.748953 0.250920 26 vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 27 vn -1.000000
>   -0.000000 -0.000000 28 vn -0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000 29 vn -0.000001 0.000000 1.000000 30 vn 1.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 31 vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000001 32 vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000 33 vn -0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 34 usemtl Material_ray.png 35 s off 36 f 5/1/1 1/2/1 4/3/1 37 f 5/1/1 4/3/1 8/4/1 38 f 3/5/2 7/6/2 8/7/2 39 f 3/5/2
>   8/7/2 4/8/2 40 f 2/9/3 6/10/3 3/5/3 41 f 6/10/4 7/6/4 3/5/4 42 f 1/2/5
>   5/1/5 2/9/5 43 f 5/1/6 6/10/6 2/9/6 44 f 5/1/7 8/11/7 6/10/7 45 f
>   8/11/7 7/12/7 6/10/7 46 f 1/2/8 2/9/8 3/13/8 47 f 1/2/8 3/13/8 4/14/8

Comment: `std::ifstream` + `std::ifstream::operator>>`.

Comment: "so i cannot really find anything useful currenly" - it's almost like there weren't any other websites on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `std::ifstream` something like this:

```
string file_name;
// ...
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open(file_name);

ifs >> v.x;
ifs >> v.y;
ifs >> v.z;
```

Comment: `ifstream ifs(file_name);` works too as a shorthand.

Comment: i would do that but the file is also contains character so how do slove this

Comment: @user3761699 if they contain character then also std::ifstream will work